# How I can change my company name showing in my itunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Greeting, hope you all are doing well there.

I want to change in my itunes connect. I want to change its company name which shows whenever someone see my apps.

Please check attached image for more detail.

thanks,

Cp

[image]

Comment: The only way this can be changed is by contacting Apple Support

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about iTunes connect customer support.

Comment: Extremely useful question. +1.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can only choose a company name the first time you publish an app in iTunes Connect.

Quote from [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/2_BeforeYouBegin/BeforeYouBegin.html):

> If you have enrolled in the Apple Developer Program as a company, the
>   first time you add a new app in iTunes Connect, you are presented with
>   the Company Name page. On this page you set your company’s name that
>   applies to each app you add to your developer account for distribution
>   on the App Store. If you have enrolled as an individual, the company
>   name is your developer or seller name.
>
> Important: You cannot edit your company’s name after submitting it on
>   this page. The settings you specified will apply to all apps added to
>   your account, so be sure they are correct before continuing. Do not
>   include Apple trademarks.

Your only chance is to contact [Apple developer support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php) and ask them to change your name. They may require additional documentation from you on why you need to change it. All in all a quite long process that I've had to go through once...

Comment: I have a single developer account, will I be allowed to change it to my company name. My company name is not registered anywhere, except that I own the domain :)

Comment: As stated by Apple above, individual developer accounts will always be under the developer's name. Even if you are the owner of a sole proprietorship company that is listed in your country's company register and even if you have a D.U.N.S. number for that company, Apple will still consider you as an individual developer.

Comment: I dig this topic up; what exactly is a "quite long process" ?

Comment: If I delete all the apps and resubmit a new app, Will I get a new popup for enter the updated company's name

Comment: @aguilarpgc: no

Comment: This isn't quite accurate any more — if you go to https://developer.apple.com, Account, Membership, there's now a "Need to edit this information?" link. Note that you'll only see it if you're the Team Agent.